# render a variable in unescaped html in mustachejs

Tags: javascript, html, mustache

I know that using 3 brackets will unescape html but what if this html has a variable that I want to render e.g.

```
{
 body: "<p> this is a {{message}} </p>",
 message: "Hello World"
}
```

```
{{{ body }}}
```

renders

```html
this is a
```

I want it to be

```html
this is a Hello World
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the doc, this is not possible:

> **Lambdas**
>
> When the value is a callable object, such as a function or lambda, the
>   object will be invoked and passed the block of text. The text passed
>   is the literal block, unrendered. **{{tags}}** will not have been expanded
>   - the lambda should do that on its own. In this way you can implement filters or caching.

However, since you can use functions for rendering, it is easy to include the message in your rendered function:

```js
let view = {
  message: "message in a bottle ",
  body() {
    return `<p> this is a ${this.message}. </p>`
  }
}

let output = Mustache.render("{{{ body }}}", view)
console.log(output)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/janl/mustache.js@v3.1.0/mustache.min.js"></script>
```

If your goal is only to wrap your body in a `<p>`, the most elegant (and fitting to the [doc](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html)) solution would be:

```js
let view = {
  message: "message in a bottle ",
  body() {
    return (text, render) => `<p>${render(text)}</p>`
  }
}

let output = Mustache.render(`
{{#body}}
  This is a {{message}}.
{{/body}}
`, view)
console.log(output)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/janl/mustache.js@v3.1.0/mustache.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the value of the object itself you need to make it return the string you want to build in a function call that can reference `this`

The wat shown below is plain javascript.

```html
<p id="test"></p>

<script>
    var item = {
     message: "Hello World",
     get body() { 
        return "<p> this is a " + this.message + "</p>" 
      }
    };

    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = item.body;
</script>
```

reference link: https://clubmate.fi/self-referencing-object-literal-in-javascript/

Comment: This might help OP since mustache allows usage of functions to generate data. But as-is this answer is not about mustache...

Comment: @UlysseBN - fair point :) somehow this seems to be a principle that you should know anyways before starting handlebars or anything else for that matter :) those frameworks are built on the core functionality of JS and it wouldn't suprise me that this approach is what runs "under the hood" of handlebars :P 

But - you're still correct about the scope of my answer :)